# Join a two different ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, java.util.concurrent

I wanted to join two threads that are getting executed in ExecutorService.

```
public class CURD {

  public static ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
  
 @Autowired
 Logging logging;

  public void Update(List<? extends HBase> save, List<? extends HBase> delete) {
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println("Started Main Thread...");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1500);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("End Main Thread...");
        },"Thread-1");

        logging.setPredecessor(t);
        executorService.submit(t);
    }
}
```

Second Class:
This class thread should wait for the first thread to complete.
But it doesn't wait for the first thread to complete.
I am not sure if this is the right way to do it.

Please can someone let me know how to join two threads that are getting executed in an ExecutorService?

```
import static com.demo.executorService;

public class Logging {
   
   private Thread predecessor;
   public void  setPredecessor(Thread t) {
        this.predecessor = t;
    }

  private void loggingInfo() {
      Thread run = new Thread( () ->{
                try {
                    if (predecessor != null) {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Started");
                        predecessor.join();
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Finished");
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            addTask(run);
   }

   public void addTask(Runnable run) {
        System.out.println("Runnable Thread logAround.....");
        CompletableFuture.runAsync((run), executorService).exceptionally(ex -> {
            System.out.println("exception occurred " + ex);
            return null;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one wants to synchronize among a set of threads one can use
the Java [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) class:

> A synchronization aid that allows a set of threads to all wait for
> each other to reach a common barrier point. CyclicBarriers are useful
> in programs involving a fixed sized party of threads that must
> occasionally wait for each other. The barrier is called cyclic because
> it can be re-used after the waiting threads are released.

To achieve that, first create the `CyclicBarrier` object with the correspondent number of *parties*, namely:

```
private final CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(NUMBER_OF_PARIES);
```

Formally from the Java doc one can read that parties are:

> the number of threads that must invoke {@link #await} before the barrier is tripped

Informally, *parties* are the number of threads that will have to call the cyclic barrier and *wait*, before all of them can move forward.

Afterward, you need to pass the barrier instance object reference to each of the threads that should wait, and invoke `wait` (*i.e.,*  `barrier.await()`), accordingly. Something as follows:

```
  public void Update(..., CyclicBarrier barrier) {
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println("Started Main Thread...");
            try {
                 Thread.sleep(1500);
                 barrier.await(); // <--- wait on the barrier
            } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
            System.out.println("End Main Thread...");
        },"Thread-1");
        ...
    }
```

Repeat this  process to the other threads that must wait. Ensure that the number of parties (*i.e.,* `NUMBER_OF_PARIES`) matches the number of threads that should wait on the cyclic barrier, otherwise deadlocks will occur.

Now that you are using the `cyclic barrier` you can clean up some parts of your code, for instance, you can remove all the logic related to the field `predecessor` of the `Logging` class.

If you just want to make `Thread 2` wait for `Thread 1`, then you can use [CountDownLatch](http://CountDownLatch), instead.

> A synchronization aid that allows one or more threads to wait until a
> set of operations being performed in other threads completes. A
> CountDownLatch is initialized with a given count. The await methods
> block until the current count reaches zero due to invocations of the
> countDown() method, after which all waiting threads are released and
> any subsequent invocations of await return immediately. This is a
> one-shot phenomenon -- the count cannot be reset. If you need a
> version that resets the count, consider using a CyclicBarrier.

First create the `CountDownLatch` object with only `1` count:

```
private final CountDownLatch block_thread2 = new CountDownLatch(1);
```

and pass it to the `Thread 2`, and since you want this thread to wait for the `Thread 1`, call `block_thread2.await();`

```
      Thread run = new Thread( () ->{
                   try {
                        ....
                        block_thread2.await(); // wait for Thread 2
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // deal with it
                   }
     });
            ...
```

and to the `Thread 1` add  `wait.countDown();`:

```
  public void Update(...) {
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
                   System.out.println("Started Main Thread...");
                   try {
                        Thread.sleep(1500);
                        wait.countDown();
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // deal with it
            }
            System.out.println("End Main Thread...");
        },"Thread-1");
        ...
    }
```

So, in this manner, `Thread 2` will wait for `Thread 1`, but `Thread 1` will never wait for `Thread 2`.